# How to call result of First Page from Third Page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have three page

### FirstPage.dart

enter code here

```
final result=await  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second_page');
if(result!=null){
//api calling goes here..
}
```

## SecondPage.dart

```
final result=await  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/third_page',result:101);
```

## ThirdPage.dart

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(101)
```

---

Note: Page is redireced to First page but result of First Page is not getting call. Please help for this solution as fast as possible.

Comment: Add the code from SecondPage, where you do the pop action, please. Are you giving the result variable when Calling the pop method?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, implements a state management like Provider, or pass the argument in the navigator using Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(_=>YourPage(yourArguments) )) and then, your page has to receive that arguments in its contrustor

Comment: Thank you for the direction, and its working fine in the same manner..